# The !preg_match() function in a condition statement is false always

Tags: php, mysql

Please see the following code. I think it is correct. When I use another characters 
with the letters and numbers or singly, I should see the `only the letters and numbers` messages. But even when I use only the letters and the numbers, I see the `only the letters and numbers` again.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
$login = $_POST['pass'];
$repass = $_POST['repass'];
if(empty($username) || empty($login) || empty($repass)) {

echo "one or more fields is empty";
}

 else if(!preg_match("[A-Za-z0-9]",$username) || !preg_match("[A-Za-z0-9]", $login) || !preg_match("[A-Za-z0-9]",$repass)){

echo "only the letters and numbers";
}

        else if($login != $repass){

echo "the password is not match with the repassword";
}
        else {

        $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "hello");
if(!$connection) { echo "error in connecting to the database";}
        else {


$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='$username'");

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($rows == 1 ) {

echo "there is this username currently";
}
        else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (username, login, repass) VALUES ('$username', '$login', '$repass')";

if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {



echo "you are register";

} else{
        echo "please again";
 mysqli_close($connection);}
        } } } }
else {
echo "invalid request";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You need regex delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a delimiter

```
else if(preg_match("#[^a-z0-9]+#i",$username))
```

Comment: Correct. In addition to that, from http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php , preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred - so you your check must be improved. In the above code, when an error occurs, preg_match returns FALSE, and thus the else if (...) succeeds which is not what you want it to do.

Comment: @M0rtiis: The problem solved and thank you. But now I found a new problem and this that when I use in the `username` filed, for example the `@M0rtiis` or the `#M0rtiis`, my code accept such names.

Comment: @android use anchors for matching beginning and ending the string: `#^[a-z0-9]+$#i`